# Flutter ios build error deprecated packages with ios deployment target 10

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-build

hello i have a flutter project. Android part works fine. i get a many error when i want to compile ios.

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
  ...
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/store_redirect-2.0.1/ios/Classes/StoreRedirectPlugin.m:27:48: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first
    deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
                                                   ^~~~~~~
                                                   openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/store_redirect/store_redirect-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first
    deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.3.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:48: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first
    deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                                   ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:13:3: warning:
    'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      UILocalNotification *_launchNotification;
      ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:335:4: warning:
    'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    - (UILocalNotification *)buildStandardUILocalNotification:
       ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:935:34: warning:
    'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
                                     ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:205:41: warning:
    'scheduledLocalNotifications' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          [UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications;
                                            ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIApplication.h:243:68: note: 'scheduledLocalNotifications' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nullable,nonatomic,copy) NSArray<UILocalNotification *> *scheduledLocalNotifications API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's
    -[UNUserNotificationCenter getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:]", ios(4.0, 10.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
                                                                       ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:210:5: warning:
    'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [notifications objectAtIndex:i];
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:316:5: warning:
    'UIUserNotificationType' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        UIUserNotificationType notificationTypes = 0;
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:17:32: note: 'UIUserNotificationType' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIUserNotificationType) {
                                   ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:318:28: warning:
    'UIUserNotificationTypeSound' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          notificationTypes |= UIUserNotificationTypeSound;
                               ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:17:32: note: 'UIUserNotificationType' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIUserNotificationType) {
                                   ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:321:28: warning:
    'UIUserNotificationTypeAlert' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          notificationTypes |= UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
                               ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:17:32: note: 'UIUserNotificationType' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIUserNotificationType) {
                                   ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:324:28: warning:
    'UIUserNotificationTypeBadge' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNAuthorizationOptions
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          notificationTypes |= UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
                               ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:17:32: note: 'UIUserNotificationType' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIUserNotificationType) {
                                   ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:326:5: warning:
    'UIUserNotificationSettings' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationSettings
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:44:12: note: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:327:37: warning:
    'UIUserNotificationSettings' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationSettings
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificationTypes
                                        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIUserNotificationSettings.h:44:12: note: 'UIUserNotificationSettings' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIUserNotificationSettings : NSObject
               ^

    
                                           ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIApplication.h:239:1: note: 'scheduleLocalNotification:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (void)scheduleLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    addNotificationRequest:withCompletionHandler:]", ios(4.0, 10.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);  // copies notification
    ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:485:5: warning:
    'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        UILocalNotification *notification =
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:528:40: warning:
    'scheduleLocalNotification:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    addNotificationRequest:withCompletionHandler:] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
                                           ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIApplication.h:239:1: note: 'scheduleLocalNotification:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (void)scheduleLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    addNotificationRequest:withCompletionHandler:]", ios(4.0, 10.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);  // copies notification
    ^
  
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIApplication.h:239:1: note: 'scheduleLocalNotification:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (void)scheduleLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    addNotificationRequest:withCompletionHandler:]", ios(4.0, 10.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);  // copies notification
    ^
```

...

```
                                              ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIApplication.h:243:68: note: 'scheduledLocalNotifications' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nullable,nonatomic,copy) NSArray<UILocalNotification *> *scheduledLocalNotifications API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's
    -[UNUserNotificationCenter getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:]", ios(4.0, 10.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
                                                                       ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:618:7: warning:
    'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          UILocalNotification *localNotification = [notifications objectAtIndex:i];
          ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:623:13: warning:
    'cancelLocalNotification:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers:] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                cancelLocalNotification:localNotification];
                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIApplication.h:240:1: note: 'cancelLocalNotification:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    removePendingNotificationRequestsWithIdentifiers:]", ios(4.0, 10.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
    ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:638:40: warning:
    'cancelAllLocalNotifications' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    removeAllPendingNotificationRequests] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
                                           ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIApplication.h:241:1: note: 'cancelAllLocalNotifications' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (void)cancelAllLocalNotifications API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenter
    removeAllPendingNotificationRequests]", ios(4.0, 10.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
    ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:920:5: warning:
    'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        UILocalNotification *launchNotification =
        ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:921:10: warning:
    'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's UNNotificationRequest
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            (UILocalNotification *)[launchOptions
             ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UILocalNotification.h:18:12: note: 'UILocalNotification' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UILocalNotification : NSObject<NSCopying, NSCoding>
               ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:922:26: warning:
    'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications Framework's
    -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:] [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
                             ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Heade
    rs/UIApplication.h:513:50: note: 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    UIKIT_EXTERN UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey const UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey     NS_SWIFT_NAME(localNotification)
    API_DEPRECATED("Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:]", ios(4.0,
    10.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos); // userInfo contains a UILocalNotification
                                                     ^
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:934:1: warning:
    implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    ^
    In module 'Flutter' imported from
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.h:1:
    /Users/obb/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterPlugin.h:98:1: note: method
    'application:didReceiveLocalNotification:' declared here
    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
    ^
    35 warnings generated.
    /* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
    /Users/obb/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.3.2/ios/Storyboards/WebView.storyboard:global: warning: This file is set to build
    for a version older than the deployment target. Functionality may be limited. [9]
    lib/main.dart:43:79: Error: Too many positional arguments: 2 allowed, but 3 found.
    Try removing the extra positional arguments.
    const AndroidNotificationChannel andChannle = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
                                                                                  ^
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/lib/src/platform_specifics/android/notification_channel.dart:10:9: Context:
    Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      const AndroidNotificationChannel(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    lib/main.dart:83:14: Error: Can't return a value from a void function.
          return onSelectNotification(payload ?? '');
                 ^
    lib/view/basestate/notification.dart:44:73: Error: Too many positional arguments: 2 allowed, but 3 found.
    Try removing the extra positional arguments.
            var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
                                                                            ^
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/lib/src/platform_specifics/android/notification_details.dart:12:9: Context:
    Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
      const AndroidNotificationDetails(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:13:11: Error: Member
    not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
        Error.throwWithStackTrace(exception, stackTrace);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:16:9: Error: Member
    not found: 'Error.throwWithStackTrace'.
      Error.throwWithStackTrace(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging_platform_interface-3.2.0/lib/src/method_channel/utils/exception.dart:11:7: Error: A
    non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Never' doesn't allow null.
    Never convertPlatformException(Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
          ^
    Failed to package /Users/obb/Desktop/orbike.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel
```

My PodFile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

....

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
    end
  end
end
```

- I tried IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET and platform as 9,10,11
- i tried `flutter clean;pod update;pod install;`
- I tried changing pubspec.yaml package versions

> NOTE:If I do IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 9, I get firebase min deployment target error in `pod install`.

**My flutter version is 2.8.1 and I don't want to update**

**I've had a similar issue before.. I fixed it by creating a new flutter project and moving all my code there. Is there an easier solution?**

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: have you tried downgrading firebase messaging package in pubspec?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to point out the plugins that you're using. Try [upgrading](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/upgrade#upgrading-packages) the packages used in the Flutter project by running `flutter pub upgrade`, then run `flutter pub get`. Run the project again on iOS and see if it builds successfully. If not, try rebuilding the iOS build by deleting the **/ios** in the project folder and generating a new one by running `flutter create --platforms=ios`